# PhoneGap/Cordova Android app has no access to internet via 3g/4g alone

Tags: android, cordova

I'm having an issue with only a handful of users reporting that they are not able to use my application (which requires internet access) over mobile network internet. They are not able to access the network at all to sign in to the application. But the app works perfectly over a wi-fi connection.

The request is obviously cross domain and the server API is programmed to accept cross-domain requests.

Logging on the server shows no call is even received when the user tries.

The jQuery Ajax call always returns the fail callback as soon as the process is started.

I have already checked the usual suspects and they are all ok.

```
<access origin="*" />
```

And in my Android Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I've already tried getting the user to completely uninstall the app, and reinstall again. No dice.

I'm stumped. Can anyone point me out to a possible solution here.

Using Cordova version 3.1.0 and Android Minimum SDK is 15 (4.0.1)

Thanks so much.

Comment: Strange, I've never heard of anything like this. Is there any way you can ask them which devices this is failing on? Maybe we can find a pattern...it seems like this would be one of those goofy hardware inconsistencies.

Comment: DROID RAZR MAXX HD and Samsung Galaxy Note 3

Comment: And both are on Android > 4.0.1 I hope?
Some similar queries are showing people having problem with ajax over cellular on other Samsung devices. I remember Samsung devices generally have more issues than others.
Have you been able to reproduce it yourself personally? It'd be useful to see if they can hit your server from the regular mobile browser. Maybe you can mock up a page with the same ajax request and ask those users to visit the page on the browser.

Comment: Maybe it's because of high 3g latency. Did you set a timeout for the requests?

Comment: I haven't set a timeout. And yes, one of the devices is 4.1.2 and the other is 4.3

I'm actually making them a small app using the exact same plugins and js files, and only outputting debug info for them to email me. Lets see how that goes. I posted here hoping it was a more widespread issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally got to the bottom of it.

It was a DNS issue. Our primary web application is a Google App Engine hosted app, and we use wildcard subdomains in that.

The Android application also contacts a subdomain under the same domain (mobile.{domain}.com) but this is hosted on a separate server and does not rely on GAE. Calls from the Android app while on the mobile network kept going to the GAE app rather than the API endpoint I set up at mobile.{domain}.com, guess it was some sort of DNS propagation issue for the mobile internet.

But here's the kicker, the subdomains were not new, they are a couple of years old.

To solve it, I set up a .net of our domain to point to the same server, set up an endpoint and now all is well.