# Cordova Android app has no internet access on SOME devices

Tags: android, cordova

I ran into a strange problem and I can't find any solution how to fix it.

On some devices (not all), the app has no internet access. I can't reproduce the problem with any emulator configuration.

The list of devices with problems:
- Galaxy S6 Edge, Android 5.0
- Galaxy S5, Android 5.0
- Galaxy Note, Android 4.1
- TrekStor tolino tab 8.9, Android 4.2
- Xperia L, Android 4.2

Anyone else there with such a strange problem? And please remember, only SOME devices has the problem, must of the installations runs as expected.

In the config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

In my manifest the settings are correct:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhoneGap/Cordova Android app has no access to internet via 3g/4g alone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913043/phonegap-cordova-android-app-has-no-access-to-internet-via-3g-4g-alone)

Comment: I don't think that my problem is because of a DNS issue as described in the other thread. I already found that one before I posted my question here.
But anyway - thanks for your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

finally I solved the problem.

In config.xml I had a min. Android version included

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15"/>
```

which corrupted my Android build. After removing this, the app runs fine on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

@Stephan Beutel

You did not list any URLs? Is it possible you are having the domains blocked? Are they all using port 80 or 433 for web access?

Jesse

Comment: The calls uses port 80, standard http REST calls. The curious thing is that only some devices can't access the internet.

Comment: Your information is vague, so this is the best answer you will get. And since you neither name device (that cannot connect) nor name URLS (that you cannot connect to), there is insufficient to make any determination - beyond the obvious.

Comment: The devices are listed in my question. The URL I want to access is http://www.jumplog.net/<php script> where the REST interface is accessable.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Got new glasses - having problems with them. I would try a simple http request (GET), then work from there. Some REST services, namely parse.com and firebase.com require SSL. It is remotely possible that your SSL certificates are out of date on these machines. However, Phonegap has it's on cert, so this is making no sense to me. I have [Demo apps](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/phonegap/demos/PUBLIC.Apps.html), but sadly none on basic connection. I'll add that to my list of TODO. Sorry can't help much.